# Handling concurrency of Firestore transactions in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing an app using firebase as backend and i have a google cloud function that is triggered after a document is create in a collection named "Requests". The logic behind this function is that the new document is compared with the already existing documents in the same collection and if the new document match with another based on certain parameters a transaction is executed.
In this transaction i delete both documents and create a document in another collection.
The problem is that if several documents are created almost at the same time, the transaction behaves in an undesired way, taking the same document for more than one couple.
As I understand it, if at least one of the operations within a transaction fails, the transaction is rolled back.
But in this case it doesn't make sense since it would be assumed that with deleting a document in one transaction, it should fail when trying to delete it in another transaction.
What I want is that a request be taken only once and then be eliminated, not that it be taken for more than one couple

This is my transaction:

```
db.runTransaction(transaction => {
            return transaction.get(requestsRef.doc(docId)).then(doc => {

                var data = doc.data();
                var arrayUsers = [uid, data.uid];
                transaction.set(db.collection('chatRoom').doc(uid.substring(0, 8) + data.uid.substring(0, 7) + doc.id.substring(0, 7))
                    , {
                        arrayUsers: arrayUsers,
                        uid1: uid,
                        uid2: uid2,
                    })
                transaction.delete(db.collection('Requests').doc(doc.id));
                transaction.delete(db.collection('Requests').doc(snap.id));

                return null;
            });
        }).then(result => {
            console.log("OK");
            return null;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("ERR");
            console.error(err);
        });
```

What i expect:

1. user #1 create request #1
2. user #2 create request #2
3. user #3 create request #3
4. request #1 and #2 are removed and i create a chat room with user #1 and user #2
5. request #3 is kept on hold

What happens:

1. user #1 create request #1
2. user #2 create request #2
3. user #3 create request #3
4. request #1 and #2 are removed and i create a chat room with user #1 and user #2

5)request #1 and #3 are removed and i create a chat room with user #1 and user #3

Comment: It's not clear to me what the observed behavior is, and how that's different that what you'd like instead.  It might help if you edit the question to show your observations step by step.

Comment: Sorry, what I want is that a request be taken only once and then be eliminated, not that it be taken for more than one couple
since according to the transaction, the same document is deleted twice without producing errors, that is what I do not understand

Comment: It's still not clear to me.  As I suggested, **edit the question** to walk through the specific sequence of events that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: thanks @DougStevenson , i already edit the question

Comment: what do u mean by request #3 is kept on hold?

Comment: @andresmijares that this request is waiting for a new request to be entered to form a new couple